# securityfilter: how to get user logged

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

I'm working with secucrityfilter and I don't really get how to get the user logged.

What I try yo say is this. When you're not extending from securityfilter, when someone logged, you save the user in the session:

```
session.putValue("user", user);
```

So when you're redirected to the index, to get the user

```
session.getAttribute("user")
```

How do I get the user if I'm working with securityfilter?

Comment: what is `securityfilter`? Is it a Filter that you are implementing?

Comment: http://securityfilter.sourceforge.net - a dependency in the project

Comment: If user login is already managed by security filter, you can use one of these methods i guess: request.getRemoteUser(), request.isUserInRole(), and request.getUserPrincipal()